# JSON response parsing in batches & session id handling using RESTful-BULK API

Tags: bulk

As of now i can see, Bulk API samples in JAVA using input as CSV files. but i need an example using JSON input with Bulk Rest API to send the data from java application to salesforce. if any body has sample code please help me.

Comment: Hi Nagarjuna, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and visit the [help]. The format here is *specific* questions and answers. Posts asking for code samples are off-topic on this site and will usually be closed. If you make an attempt to implement your solution and get stuck on a specific detail, then asking about it here will likely be on topic.

Answer (score 2):

From the Bulk API Developer Guide's [Sample JSON File](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_json_sample_file.htm) page, you'll find the following sample JSON:

```
[
   {
      "Name" : "Xytrex Co.",
      "Description" : "Industrial Cleaning Supply Company",
      "Account Number" : "ABC15797531"
   },
   {
      "Name" : "Watson and Powell, Inc.",
      "Description" : "Law firm. New York Headquarters",
      "Account Number" : "ABC24689753"     
   }
]
```